# Media Creation Tool for Windows 10 not starting

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10-upgrade

Microsoft Surface Pro 3 - Windows 8.1

The automated Microsoft update for Windows 10 never has advised that the upgrade was available; yet I have been recieving multiple Windows 10 upgrade failure messages daily in Windows Update history.

I have attempted to utilize the Windows Update Manager to upgrade to Windows 10.
It will complete the download and then prompt for "Check your PC". When selected it fails with an error code of 8007005 for which I can find no information.

It was suggested that I utilize the Media Creation Tool versus the Windows Update.  For this I downloaded the 64-bit version (I'm running on a Microsoft Surface Pro 3 with 64-bit version of Windows 8.1)

In an attempt to run the Media Creation Tool, I:
 1. Stopped BITS service  (to stop the automated download)
 2. Deleted ~BT directory  (to remove the prior download)
 3. Deleted WS directory (to remove the prior Media creation items)
 4. Deleted files under Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download (to remove the prior download)
 4. Double Click MediaCreationTool64
 5. Get the Run as Administrator Dialog Box Click YES
 6. Receive spinning dial for about 2 seconds

Then nothing.

I downloaded the Windows 8.1 Media Creation utility to test access permissions and that process brings up the proper screens. (I did not run it any further than getting the initial screen)

Comment: You shouldn't have to do any of that....

Answer (score 0):

Wait 15 seconds for it to open.

Also try to clean boot and run the tool again.

Download all windows updates and install. ?there is an important one that prepares pc for windows 10 and puts a windows icon in system tray. then open it and request your copy.

The windows media creation tool from my experience after running the executable then clicking yes to allow to run takes more time than one would expect for example it has taken more than 10 seconds to open for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I've edited answer now to read better and a third choice of installing updates. I felt the original answer which included the clean boot was considered an answer since that worked for me. i appreciate your feedback David Postill.