# How to make Windows 10 Media Creation tool finish & not disappear

Tags: windows-10

When running the Windows Media Creation tool it seems to disappear and not finish. How do I get the tool to finish and complete the upgrade from windows 8.1 to windows 10 on my computer?

The steps I take are to:
Run the tool 
Choose upgrade my pc
then the Downloading Windows 10 completes ( takes a bit of time ) 
Then it completes the Verifying Download ( relatively quick ) 
Then when it goes to Creating Windows 10 media it will get halfway and 
Then the window disappears 
I've had this happen over 5 times now. I've tried clean booting also.

How do I get the tool to complete and upgrade my pc to win 10?

Thank in advance for any info.

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](http://superuser.com/questions/951843/media-creation-tool-for-windows-10-not-starting)

Comment: I don't feel its a duplicate since the other question is regarding the tool not starting. This question is after the tool starts and completes some steps

Comment: Why not just get it to download the ISO to you, and then you can burn that to a DVD, or USB key and use that to do the upgrade?

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion; the iso is not how I want to upgrade. the negative for from what i read is you need the win10 key which you get from upgrading pc first then you can use the iso. also you have to delete the recovery partition on the drive which i'm hesitant in doing.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem on some computers myself. What I did is to run a recovery on the original OS (I use recovery from producers) and then run the media created from scratch. It may not be the easiest way, but it works.